# Response Em RestFull

Tags: java, json

Boa Noite pessoal, Sou novo em WebService e estou com a seguinte dúvida, como faço para fazer um Response da classe criada em java?

Até o momento fiz isso no meu código:

```java
package alarme;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class BotaoController {

    public BotaoController(){
        Botao teste = new Botao(1,true);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/botao/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta declarar um método Java que recebe os parâmetros da requisição que você usará e que retorna o que você quer:

```
@GetMapping("/botao/{id}")
public Botao getButtonById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Botao teste = new Botao(1,true);
    return teste;
}
```

O Spring permite que você declare esses métodos com os seus próprios tipos de retorno (`Botao` no exemplo acima), ou encapsulados numa `ResponseEntity` para casos em que você precisa retornar outros status:

```
@GetMapping("/botao/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Botao> getButtonById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Botao botao = userRepository.getOne(id);
    if(botao == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(botao);
}
```

A [documentação oficial](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/index.html) tem bastante exemplos sobre o assunto.